# Unable to change the Font Awesome icon color when moving the mouse over the icon

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I have the following Font Awesome icon:-

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-marker fa-lg" ></i></a> |
```

by default the icon color will be blank and blue when hover over it. now i want to change the icon color to red and blue on hover, so i add the following:-

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-marker fa-lg" style="color:#ff4c4c;"></i></a> |
```

but i lost the hover color, so i added this css:-

```
.fa-marker:hover
{color:blue}
```

but did not have any effect. any advice how i can change the hover color for the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important` which ignores all other styles, the reason your code wasn't working was the style priority, all the styles given directly from `style=""`attribute have higher priority

```css
.fa-marker:hover {
  color: blue !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-marker fa-lg" style="color:#ff4c4c;"></i></a>
```